# BULK IMPORT data with unique date value

Tags: sql-server

I am initially getting my data from a csv file as such. For a given id, I cannot have a duplicate date. What I like to do is to add random seconds to date so it is unique. The approach I have below does not work as all the dates have the random seconds whereas what I need is for each records to have a unique seconds. Any assistance would be helpful. It would be nice to add a random date as it is being imported.

```
    CREATE TABLE #TBL (dt DateTime, id int);

    BULK INSERT #TBL FROM 'C:\Import\file1.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',');

 // This updated all date fields to the same seconds. I want each individual row to have a random seconds field.

    UPDATE #TBL 
    SET #TBL.dt = DATEADD(second,(rand()*60), #TBL.dt);
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't have duplicate dates? You have got duplicate dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick way would be

```
UPDATE #TBL 
  SET #TBL.dt = DATEADD(second,(#TBL.id), #TBL.dt);
```

As long as you don't import more than 86,400 records at a time. (number of seconds in a day)
This assumes id's start at 0 if that isn't true, this is going to get messier. Random wouldn't solve your problem anyway, it could come up with the same value more than once. You are digging a big hole to fall into here.